# RTK Query - problem with api responses because of "capture network traffic" enabled in Smartlook configuration

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have a project with reactjs toolkit and RTK Query.

To fetch data from API my api looks ex. like this:

```
export const studentsListApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'studentsListApi',
  tagTypes: ['StudentsList'],
  baseQuery,
  keepUnusedDataFor: 0,
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    studentsList: build.query<
      StudentsListApiResponse,
      { showInactive?: boolean } & TPagination & StudentFilters
    >({
      query: ({ page, queryString, showInactive, pageSize, ...filters }) => ({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `/myStudents/search?${toQueryParams({ page, pageSize: pageSize || PAGE_SIZE })}`,
        body: {
          queryString,
          showInactive,
          ...filters,
        },
        invalidatesTags: ['StudentsList'],
      }),
      providesTags: ['StudentsList'],
    }),
  }),
});
```

When enable "capture network traffic" option in Smartlook some requests are rejected - I can see in network that they are returned from API, but redux takes them as rejected.

```
{
  type: 'studentsListApi/executeQuery/rejected',
  payload: {
    status: 'FETCH_ERROR',
    error: 'TypeError: Failed to construct \'Request\': Cannot construct a Request with a Request object that has already been used.'
  },
  meta: {
    baseQueryMeta: {
      request: {}
    },
    RTK_autoBatch: true,
    arg: {
      type: 'query',
      subscribe: true,
      subscriptionOptions: {
        pollingInterval: 0
      },
      endpointName: 'studentsList',
      originalArgs: {
        page: 1,
        showInactive: false,
        pageSize: 9
      },
      queryCacheKey: 'studentsList({"page":1,"pageSize":9,"showInactive":false})'
    },
    requestId: '7J39XeWGziSLCxZ7WL0eX',
    rejectedWithValue: true,
    requestStatus: 'rejected',
    aborted: false,
    condition: false
  },
  error: {
    message: 'Rejected'
  }
}
```